# Re-rendering component doesn't update object inside functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Depending on the weather, a certain type of icon should show up.

Within my `Weather` component, I've created an object that contains all the relevant icons. I did this, rather than add it to `state`, because according to React:

> Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your
>   component? If so, it isn’t state.

And the icon can be computed based on the value of `this.currentWeather.main`.

Everything works fine on the first run, but if you change cities (to one with a different weather type), the icon remains the same. I cannot figure out why. (ie. Try using Tustin, US ---> Rochester, US)

I've tried to `console.log(currentIcon)`, and I get a symbol object, and within it, it has the correct property value, but it does not get displayed correctly.

My understanding is that when state is updated (via the second time you enter in another city and country), that the `Weather` component should have re-rendered, and all of the code before the `return` statement should have been re-run, which I believe it did.

Just not sure why the `{currentIcon}` in the `return` statement isn't reflecting that change.

I would love an answer, but moreso, I would love to know **why** the display isn't being updated.

```js
const root = document.querySelector('.root');

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      unit: '',
      currentWeather: {
        main: '',
        desc: '',
        temp: '',
      }
    }
    
    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
    this.unitHandler = this.unitHandler.bind(this);
  }
  
  getWeather(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
    const appID = 'bf6cdb2b4f3c1293c29610bd1d54512b';
    
    const currentWeatherURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&units=imperial&APPID=${appID}`;
    const forecastURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},${country}&units=imperial&APPID=${appID}`;
    
    //fetch CURRENT weather data ONLY
    fetch(currentWeatherURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          unit: '°F',
          currentWeather: {
           main: data.weather[0].main,
           desc: data.weather[0].description,
           temp: data.main.temp,
          }
        });
    })
    .catch(() => {console.log('something went wrong, but we caught the error')});
  }
  
  unitHandler(e) {
    function convertToCelsius(fahrenheit) {
      return ((fahrenheit-32)*5/9)
    }
    
    function convertToFahrenheit(celsius) {
      return ((celsius*9/5) + 32)
    }
    
    //if fahrenheit is checked
    if(e.target.value === 'fahrenheit') {
      const fahrenheitTemp = convertToFahrenheit(this.state.currentWeather.temp);
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        unit: '°F',
          currentWeather: {
            ...prevState.currentWeather,
            temp: fahrenheitTemp,
          }
      }));
    } 
    //otherwise, celsius is checked
    else {
      const celsiusTemp = convertToCelsius(this.state.currentWeather.temp);
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        unit: '°C',
        currentWeather: {
        ...prevState.currentWeather,
        temp: celsiusTemp,
      }
      }));
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='weather-app'>
        <LocationInput getWeather={this.getWeather} unitHandler={this.unitHandler}/>
        <CurrentWeather weatherStats={this.state.currentWeather} unit={this.state.unit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Component where you enter your City and State 
function LocationInput(props) {
  return (
    <div className='location-container'>
      <form className='location-form' onSubmit={props.getWeather}>
         <input type='text' name='city' placeholder='City'/>
         <input type='text' name='country' placeholder='Country'/>
        <button>Search</button>
        <UnitConverter unitHandler={props.unitHandler} />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

// Component to convert all units (fahrenheit <---> Celsius)
function UnitConverter(props) {
  return (
    <div className='unit-converter' onChange={props.unitHandler}>
      <label for='fahrenheit'>
        <input type='radio' name='unit' value='fahrenheit' defaultChecked/>
        Fahrenheit
      </label>
      <label for='celsius'>
        <input type='radio' name='unit' value='celsius'/>
        Celsius
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}

// Base weather component (intention of making specialized components for weekly forecast)
function Weather (props) {  
   const icons = {
        thunderstorm: <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>,
        drizzle: <i class="fas fa-cloud-rain"></i>,
        rain: <i class="fas fa-cloud-showers-heavy"></i>,
        snow: <i class="far fa-snowflake"></i>,
        clear: <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>,
        atmosphere: 'No Icon Available',
        clouds: <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>,
      };
  
  let currentIcon = icons[props.weatherStats.main.toLowerCase()];
  console.log(currentIcon);

  return (
    <div className={'weather-' + props.type}>
      <h1>{props.location}</h1>
      <h2>{props.day}</h2>
      <figure className='weather-icon'>
        <div className='weather-icon'> 
          {currentIcon}
        </div>
        <figcaption>
          <h3 className='weather-main'>{props.weatherStats.main}</h3>
          <div className='weather-desc'>{props.weatherStats.desc}</div>
          {props.weatherStats.temp && <div className='weather-temp'>{Math.round(props.weatherStats.temp)}{props.unit}</div>}
        </figcaption>
      </figure>      
    </div>
  ) 
}

// Using the specialization concept of React to create a more specific Weather component from base
function CurrentWeather(props) {
  const dateObj = new Date();
  const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
  const currentDay = days[dateObj.getDay()];
  
  return (
    <Weather 
      type={'current'} 
      weatherStats={props.weatherStats} 
      day={currentDay}
      unit={props.unit}
      />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```css
.weather-app {
  text-align: center;
}

.weather-current {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wf-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to go through, you need to try and narrow it down, whenever you fire setState your component should be re-rendered, trying putting some console logs after your render function call and just before every setState, so you can see which ones are firing etc.

Comment: Fixed your code in app sandbox: check it in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `return()` in a Class component and a Functional one, `render()` will always re-evaluate values inside of it before returning the dom, changing your props in a functional component may not return the desired value.

You may wanna try this:

```
  let currentIcon = () => icons[props.weatherStats.main.toLowerCase()]
```

inside your return, change `{currentIcon}` with `{currentIcon()}`

you may wanna consider re-naming your variable such as `let getWeatherIcon`

Comment: this is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem, try the following:

```
 const icons = {
    thunderstorm: () => <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>,
  };
```

Change each icon in that object to be a function with a return.

Hope this helps

Lloyd

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Fontawesome JS library makes some DOM manipulations to replace your icon element with svg - it works well on first page render, but when you start trying to update DOM node with React, Fontawesome lib doesn't know that it should replace that icon with new svg path.

Such DOM manipulations (when React doesn't know about them) can cause errors like this

> "react Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node."

sometimes they are rather tedious and difficult to debug.

All you need to do is to change dependency from

```
"https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js"
```

to

```
"https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"
```

The latter will use static font icons glyphs without excess DOM updates so that everything will work fine.

I've edited few typos in your code when was fixing it, you can check full working example of your app:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      unit: "",
      currentWeather: {
        main: "",
        desc: "",
        temp: ""
      }
    };

    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
    this.unitHandler = this.unitHandler.bind(this);
  }

  getWeather(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
    const appID = "bf6cdb2b4f3c1293c29610bd1d54512b";

    const currentWeatherURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&units=imperial&APPID=${appID}`;
    const forecastURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},${country}&units=imperial&APPID=${appID}`;

    //fetch CURRENT weather data ONLY
    fetch(currentWeatherURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          unit: "°F",
          currentWeather: {
            main: data.weather[0].main,
            desc: data.weather[0].description,
            temp: data.main.temp
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("something went wrong, but we caught the error");
      });
  }

  unitHandler(e) {
    function convertToCelsius(fahrenheit) {
      return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
    }

    function convertToFahrenheit(celsius) {
      return (celsius * 9) / 5 + 32;
    }

    //if fahrenheit is checked
    if (e.target.value === "fahrenheit") {
      const fahrenheitTemp = convertToFahrenheit(
        this.state.currentWeather.temp
      );
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        unit: "°F",
        currentWeather: {
          ...prevState.currentWeather,
          temp: fahrenheitTemp
        }
      }));
    }
    //otherwise, celsius is checked
    else {
      const celsiusTemp = convertToCelsius(this.state.currentWeather.temp);
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        unit: "°C",
        currentWeather: {
          ...prevState.currentWeather,
          temp: celsiusTemp
        }
      }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="weather-app">
        <LocationInput
          getWeather={this.getWeather}
          unitHandler={this.unitHandler}
        />
        <CurrentWeather
          weatherStats={this.state.currentWeather}
          unit={this.state.unit}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Component where you enter your City and State
function LocationInput(props) {
  return (
    <div className="location-container">
      <form className="location-form" onSubmit={props.getWeather}>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
        <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" />
        <button>Search</button>
        <UnitConverter unitHandler={props.unitHandler} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

// Component to convert all units (fahrenheit <---> Celsius)
function UnitConverter(props) {
  return (
    <div className="unit-converter" onChange={props.unitHandler}>
      <label for="fahrenheit">
        <input type="radio" name="unit" value="fahrenheit" defaultChecked />
        Fahrenheit
      </label>
      <label for="celsius">
        <input type="radio" name="unit" value="celsius" />
        Celsius
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

// Base weather component (intention of making specialized components for weekly forecast)
function Weather(props) {
  const icons = {
    thunderstorm: <i className="fas fa-bolt" />,
    drizzle: <i className="fas fa-cloud-rain" />,
    rain: <i className="fas fa-cloud-showers-heavy" />,
    snow: <i className="far fa-snowflake" />,
    clear: <i className="fas fa-sun" />,
    atmosphere: "No Icon Available",
    clouds: <i className="fas fa-cloud" />,
    mist: "No Icon Available"
  };

  const currentIcon = icons[props.weatherStats.main.toLowerCase()];

  return (
    <div className={"weather-common"}>
      <h1>{props.location}</h1>
      <h2>{props.day}</h2>
      <figure className="weather-icon">
        <div className="weather-icon">{currentIcon}</div>
        <figcaption>
          <h3 className="weather-main">{props.weatherStats.main}</h3>
          <div className="weather-desc">{props.weatherStats.desc}</div>
          {props.weatherStats.temp && (
            <div className="weather-temp">
              {Math.round(props.weatherStats.temp)}
              {props.unit}
            </div>
          )}
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  );
}

// Using the specialization concept of React to create a more specific Weather component from base
function CurrentWeather(props) {
  const dateObj = new Date();
  const days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday"
  ];
  const currentDay = days[dateObj.getDay()];

  return (
    <Weather
      type={"current"}
      weatherStats={props.weatherStats}
      day={currentDay}
      unit={props.unit}
    />
  );
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.weather-app {
  text-align: center;
}

.weather-current {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wf-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get an update, because components in react are being based on shallowed rendering comparison. So your code `let currentIcon = icons[props.weatherStats.main.toLowerCase()];` is deeply nested and react doesn't detect any changes. If you would like to update your component based on the changes of your icon value use shouldComponentUpdate hook and test the property that is changing, e.g.

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps){
  if (this.prevProps.weatherStats.main !== this.props.weatherStats.main){
      return true;
}
```